# Unable to use curve function to paint

Tags: bezier-curves

I have used the Curve function in the past to paint curves on to textures. Right now, when I use this function I am not able to select a paint curve point/s with the left mouse button. The Line and Space functions work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> now to add a curve point.

Comment: what does the acronym LMR stand for? i couldn't find anything on google.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie ...least meaningful resistor? ... ;-)

Comment: maybe he meant LMB? 